# How do I detect if my Python script is running in the 'Windows Terminal'

Tags: python, windows-terminal

I need to check if my Python script is running inside the [Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/) (as opposed to the CMD.exe, Powershell, bash, etc.).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

I can offer this approach:

```
is_windows_terminal = sys.platform == "win32" and os.environ.get("WT_SESSION")
```

But there may be a cleaner solution...

Answer (score 1):

I have created a package for this problem: https://pypi.org/project/AssertWT/

```py
import assertwt
assertwt.is_wt()  # True,False
```

The source code for the `is_wt` method can be found on [github](https://github.com/cvzi/AssertWT/blob/3125863ef823d5eaad1bc55155d90d9ca83f4aec/assertwt.py#L74-L88)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the parent process id (`PID`) for the process that run/spawned and run your python script and search in the tasklist in windows CMD and see this `pid` belongs to whom:

In you python script add those lines

```
import psutil
my_father_pid = str(psutil.Process().ppid())
print my_father_pid   # or print(my_father_pid) in python3
```

Now search for 'my_father_pid` that you have get, in the task list:

```
tasklist /v  | findstr "<my_father_pid>"
```